# Is botId that bot scoped? Is it permanent?

Tags: botframework

Is the botId that I receive in the webhook only bot scope or is it unique across all the bots found?

Is it permanent or can it be changed?

By `botId` I mean the id in `recipient.id` and `replyToId` that you fill in send message request to endpoint `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/v3/conversations/{{skype.idRecipient}}/activities`:

```
{
    "text": "God help us!",
    "type": "message",

    "from": {
        "id": "{{skype.idBot}}",
        "name": "bot"
    },
   "recipient": {
        "id": "{{skype.idRecipient}}",
        "name": "user"
    },

    "replyToId": "{{skype.idBot}}"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID you are talking about is unique only in the current channel (Skype/Facebook/Slack...) as it is the ID of `ChannelAccount`.
Here are some statements from documentation:

> Every bot and user has an account within each channel. The account
>   contains an identifier (id) and other informative bot non-structural
>   data, like an optional name.

Also

> Channel accounts have meaning only within their associated channel

So it's not excluded that id may be repeated on another channels.
And what about permanency, it depends on the channel you use as stated in documentation again:

> The stability of associations between IDs, accounts, mailboxes, and
>   people depends on the channel

But if you want it to be "unique across all the bots found" then you can create an id by combining `AppID`, `ChannelID` and User ID.

Also here is a quite informative [guide](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/bot-framework-guide-id/) about IDs in Bot Framework which may be helpful to you